# Return to ViewController other than the ParentViewController on dismissal of ModalViewController

Tags: ios, delegates, hierarchy, uistoryboard, uistoryboardsegue

First, have a look at this screenshot of my storyboard:

[image: storyboard layout]

It is an application for a sound map. The user can either record a new field recording or chose an existing one from the library and upload them. The ViewController where the user has to add a title/description etc. (or modifies them when coming from the library) is presented modally (on the top right).

If the user choses to cancel this and to delete the recording, he shall return to the recording screen, if he comes from there, otherwiese to the library. If he choses to save/upload the recording, he shall return to the library, where the upload progress will be displayed.

**How can I come back to the desired ViewController independently of the ParentViewController that I come from?**

I thought about unwindSegue, but that doesn't work for my layout. Then I figured out a dirty workaround where I changed the selected tab of the TabBarController. But then I also want to set up the delegate correctly to pass some data.

Any thoughts are welcome!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think changing the selectedIndex of the tab bar controller is a "dirty workaround" -- that's the way to do it, given your set up. It appears that you would want the EntryViewController (Library) to be the delegate of the EntryDetailViewController. If that's so, you could set up the delegate in the viewDidLoad method of the EntryDetailViewcontroller like this:

```
#import "DetailViewController.h"
#import "TableController.h"

@interface DetailViewController ()
@property (strong,nonatomic) UITabBarController *tbc;
@end

@implementation DetailViewController


- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.tbc = (UITabBarController *)self.presentingViewController;
    self.delegate = (TableController *)[(UINavigationController *)self.tbc.viewControllers[1] topViewController];
}


- (IBAction)saveAndUpload:(UIButton *)sender {
    [self.tbc setSelectedIndex:1];
    [self.delegate saveRecording:@"test recording"];
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}


- (IBAction)delete:(UIButton *)sender {
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

In my example, I just have two buttons to either save or cancel, and my TableController would be the same as your Library controller.

Comment: Thanks, works fine now! The tab bar selection seemed so… hard coded to me. Now everything is much clearer thanks to you!
The EntryViewController is now the delegate of the EntryDetailViewController, as you suggested and I can dismiss it from either way I came from (with an unwind segue).